# Where is the starting path set for apps created with Automator?

Tags: bash, automator

So, twenty years later I tried to adopt Launchpad one more time, failed, but it got me to start creating Automator apps from Wine apps or Java applets.

On the resulting app, I open it to move the actual app in it so it's self-contained like a true macOS app, edit icons and paths in the `X.app/Contents/document.wflow` and `X.app/Contents/Info.plist` and you can't tell the difference--works in Launchpad and everything. That is, until you move it out of its location because I'm using full paths that break as I haven't been able figure out what's the path where the script runs from in order to make them relative.

I tried creating a simple app, a Bash script with only "echo $(pwd)" on it and hopefully get that somewhere but it launched no window, of course, and there's nothing in Console.app. It just now occurred to me to redirect the output, but in case it doesn't work, could you guide me a little here?

This is the app you get from Automator...

```
X.app                      ← Why is this empty? (Except for ./Contents)
↳ Contents
⏐ ↳ documents.wflow        ← Bash script is put here, bundleID
⏐ ↳ Info.plist             ← Starting binary reference, icon, info, compatibility…
⏐ ↳ MacOS
⏐ ⏐ ↳ Application Stub     ← Generic kickstarter, runs script in documents.wflow
⏐ ↳ Resources
⏐ ⏐ ↳ AutomatorApplet.icns
```

From observation, I've learned that the binaries are always in MacOS and libraries on Resources, so I assume Application Stub is some sort of wrapper or launched or whatever it's called but the path to it `./Contents/MacOS/` is not referenced because it's like a well-known thing or specification of either Automator or macOS, thus it's not needed, the icon's path isn't referenced either, the name is though, but the path isn't--that's how I got to this conclusion. Well, that and the fact that system locations (e.g; `/System/Library/Automator/Run Shell Script.action`) are referenced.

I'm curious why is the top level directory `X.app/` otherwise empty if it wasn't for the `Contents/` directory, is this like the launchpoint? I've tried them all, but I also noticed the system was caching stuff because I could get the icons to change even after deleting them and changing their names, so I may have gotten it right but missed it because of this.

I'm using old 10.13 and Bash because I don't know AppleScript...nor Bash, but I can get by. I'm willing to learn AppleScript in small portions though.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  An application folder is just a specific arrangement of files/resources that the system treats as a single entity - see the [Mac App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH8-SW2). In the case of an Automator application, the Application Stub executable is what is used with the Automator framework to execute the various action bundles that are declared in a workflow.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing and the questions you ask are weird. To answer "I'm curious why is the top level directory X.app/ otherwise empty", well someone (Apple) came up with the structure and apps are using it, there has to be a structure. This is not a question of "why".
The answer to the question "Where is the starting path set for apps created with Automator?" is clearly visible in the structure you pasted. So what are you asking?

Comment: I'm trying to use relative paths so I can move the apps around, that's it. And, I thought I made clear I don't know anything about this other than what I got empirically, it may be clear to you guys but it's not to me--that's why I ask. The structure and all that is to show what I _think_ I know so hopefully somebody corrects me. :) If it really is the spot on the same level of Contents, could you write it as an answer?